# C++: use unique_ptr as keys in map

Tags: c++

I'm using C++, and I want to use smart pointers as keys in map. Here is what I've tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct CharPointerComparator {
    bool operator()(const unique_ptr<char>& a, const unique_ptr<char>& b) const {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};
int main() {
    map<unique_ptr<char>, int, CharPointerComparator> myMap;
    unique_ptr<char> p1 = make_unique<char>('a');
    myMap.insert(make_pair(p1, 10));
}
```

It doesn't work. I got an error:

```
/usr/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:524:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<std::unique_ptr<char>, int>::pair(std::unique_ptr<char>&, int)’
```

What's wrong here? How can I make `insert` work?

Comment: `make_pair(std::move(p1), 10)`?

Comment: @Evg Thanks, it really worked!